# How to set variable to table with mysql

Tags: mysql

Question

Help me please

I hope to set @table_variable = show tables
but  it doesn't not work

how to set variable = show tables

Comment: You need to show some of the code your working with, enough for someone to get the general idea of what your dealing with. Is this PHP, JavaScript, what kind of variable is holding your table?

Comment: show some examples of what you mean.  if you have tables foo and bar, what do you want in your variable?

Comment: what is the error message? basically you will know where you do wrong from the error message.